# WinRT C# Take photo without dialog

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

If i want take photo in WinRT, i need call this code:

```
        var ui = new CameraCaptureUI();
        ui.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(4, 3);

        var file = await ui.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

        if (file != null)
        {
            IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(fileStream);
            Photo.Source = bitmap;
        }
```

But, i want to take photo automatically, for ex. every 1 minute. So, it's impossible every minute take photo through dialog. Can I take photo program, as it is ?

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible. You must have to click the capture button

Reference: http://blog.onedevjob.com/2012/01/22/displaying-webcam-preview-in-a-metro-app-using-winrt-and-xaml/

Comment: How about Media Foundation? I try made this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj872764.aspx But this example have bug. Because externel web camera can't find. I try connect from this example to 4 different USB web cameras, and programm show error screen:(http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130227/b2QExXKS.png) And settings is not null screen(http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130227/OOme8YpT.png)

Comment: u may find any help from here
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/63dd9596-bf94-440b-847a-961cbf036e7b/